# Remove an image that was not put in uploads folder via wp_handle_upload

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm saving an image to uploads folder, but I'm using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead of [wp_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) - because I get an image in base64 and not as a file in $_FILES.

Image and certain post data are saved/updated as they should be using this functions:

- wp_insert_attachment
- wp_update_attachment_metadata

The problem is when I want to remove an old image (when saving a new one).

[wp_delete_attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) does not remove the image (it does seem to remove stuff in db though..). I am thinking the problem lies in not using wp_handle_upload. (when I upload an image via upload btn and receive it using $_FILES and then upload it with wp_handle_upload - removing works)

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the right way to remove an image in my case? 
Perhaps I can save it properly using wp_handle_upload even if I have an image in base64?

Thanks for any info.

**EDIT:** I also tried saving image with [wp_upload_bits](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) and wp_delete_attachment still did not work.

Another thing I checked: [the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L209) of wp_handle_upload function located in [`wp-admin/includes/file.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L209): I don't see an easy way to modify or copy the existing function and add a custom one which would accept base64 image instead of a file as in $_FILES. Someone has a "base64 to $_FILES" workaround perhaps?

Comment: First thing - check database. If you upload normal file with wp_handle_upload Wordpress creates some records in your database? Maybe WP can't delete this image, because you don't have any record in database. Other way - because you save your image manually(with file_put_contents) you can delete it manually(unlink in PHP).

Comment: I was thinking of using unlink, but this is not a really good solution, since you have to call multiple unlinks (all thumbs etc..). Somehow would need to get all the thumbnails that were created for each uploaded img ..

Comment: Mhm. And probably these thumbnails have some pattern in names/folders or Wordpress keeps this informations about thumbnails in database. Maybe you can write your own function to upload. There are **wp_handle_upload** and you can create **wp_handle_base64_upload**, which can be copy of **wp_handle_upload** and you can do the same things in your own function. Check where **wp_handle_upload** is.

Comment: Thought about that also: the problem is that wp_handle_upload accepts $file, which (I cite) "$file      Reference to a single element of $_FILES. Call the function once for each uploaded file."

Comment: Hm... Maybe you can execute some function before upload and overwrite $_FILES. I'm not sure, but I know you can replace $_POST, so probably $_FILES also. You can filter each file and put it into $_FILES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @KamilP said, WP inserts records in `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables.

So first you have to save your base64 images in temporary directory, then by using it's relative path and other data you can insert record in database by using [`wp_insert_attachment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata), link contains appropriate example.
This function will add image to media library.

To generate more thumbnails you can use [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) function. This function will update wp_postmeta table also with all details of image and thumbnails.

After this you can use [`wp_delete_attachment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) function to delete image from directory and database as well.

## Another solution:

- Use function from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/2219158) to generate image from base64 string.
- then get mime type, size and path of image
- create an array similar to $_FILES's.
- then pass it to [`wp_handle_upload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)

### UPDATE :

$_FILES array's structure is like this

```
array(5) {
    'name'     => string(8) "file name.extension" // file name with extension
    'type'     => string(0) "" // mime type of file, i.e. image/png
    'tmp_name' => string(0) "" // absolute path of file on disk.
    'error'    => int(2) // 0 for no error
    'size'     => int(0) // size in bytes
  }
```

You can create array like above with all details, use various file handling PHP functions to get size and mime type. Name is whatever you want to put, and tmp_name is a path of file on server where file is exists, in your case location of folder where you save your file from base64 string.

See updated link above for function which will give you image from base64 string.

Comment: How can I properly create similar array ($_FILES) with base64 img given? I do get mime-type and size beforehand already .. so that shouldn't be a problem .. Are you sure wp_handle_upload will accept 'faked' $_files?

Answer (score 2):

I actually accomplished this before I saw an answer here, so I'm providing a solution here if someone runs into the same problem. I used the function below (first one) and also using wp_delete_attachment **after** just to be sure all stuff got removed.

```php
/**
 * Attempt at removing all images in uploads folder by providing an image url 
 * Example: 
 *   - Provide http://mypage.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/uploads/2015/12/testImage.jpg
 *   - this should remove all its images created when uploading:
 *   - testImage-150x150.jpg, testImage-300x300.jpg etc and also the provided original image 
 *
 * We'r doing this because wp_delete_attachment() will not remove an image that was uploaded via a 
 * custom mytheme_upload_image() function (which is providing base64 image instead of file in $_FILES)
 *
 * TODO TODO mytheme_get_image_sizes() does not return ALL IMAGES THAT WERE CREATED (all sizes)
 */
function mytheme_remove_all_image_sizes_from_uploads($primary_image_url) {

    $pi = pathinfo($primary_image_url);

    $img_dirname = $pi['dirname'];
    $img_dirname_exploded = explode('/',$img_dirname);   
    $last_dir = array_pop($img_dirname_exploded); // month usually (two digits)
    $second_last_dir = array_pop($img_dirname_exploded); // year usually (4 digits)

    $basename = $pi['basename']; // without trailing /
    $img_name = $pi['filename'];
    $img_extension = $pi['extension'];

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $base_uploads_dir = $uploads['basedir']; // without trailing /

    $path_to_appropriate_uploads_dir =      $base_uploads_dir.'/'.$second_last_dir.'/'.$last_dir.'/';

    $img_name_to_remove = $img_name.'.'.$img_extension; // UNLINK

    if(!@unlink($path_to_appropriate_uploads_dir.$img_name_to_remove)) {
       // this image was not removed
    }

    $image_sizes = mytheme_get_image_sizes();

    foreach($image_sizes as $size) {
       $img_name_to_remove = $img_name.'-'.$size.'.'.$img_extension; // UNLINK
       $img_path = $path_to_appropriate_uploads_dir.$img_name_to_remove;

       if(mytheme_image_on_url_exists($img_path) && !@unlink($img_path)) {
          // this image was not removed
       }
    }

 }


    /**
 * Get size information for all currently-registered image sizes.
 * Found an example of this on one of the wordpress' example pages ..
 *
 * @global $_wp_additional_image_sizes
 * @uses   get_intermediate_image_sizes()
 * @return array $sizes Data for all currently-registered image sizes.
 * TODO TODO mytheme_get_image_sizes() does not return ALL IMAGES THAT WERE CREATED (all sizes)
 */
function mytheme_get_image_sizes() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $sizes = array();

    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $_size ) {

        if ( in_array( $_size, array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large' ) ) ) {

            $width = get_option( "{$_size}_size_w" );
            $height = get_option( "{$_size}_size_h" );

        } elseif ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ] ) ) {

            $width = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['width'];
            $height = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $_size ]['height'];

        }

        $img_name_end = $width."x".$height;

        if(!in_array($img_name_end,$sizes)) {
            $sizes[] = $img_name_end;
        }

    }

    // ADD CUSTOM SIZES (this one is not returned otherwise?!)
    $sizes[] = '300x200';

    return $sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is probably to just manually add `_wp_attached_file` meta value to your attachment.

Set it to the file you want deleted when the attachment is deleted.

The logic behind this is according to https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0:

`get_attached_file` returns that value to `wp_delete_attachment` which sets it as `$file`

And at the end of `wp_delete_attachment` it calls `wp_delete_file($file)`

So I'm guessing the underlying issue is that, you are never setting a value for the meta key `_wp_attached_file`.

The only downside is that I'm not sure what other processes in wp might be using that value.  But you might get lucky, perhaps none, and/or it doesn't mess anything up by setting it manually.